# PHP cannot debug, errors only on server log

Tags: php

I know there's many questions like this, tried many but without solution.
Maybe it's impossible, but i try to ask.
I'm moving our old win 2003/apache 2.0.81/php 5.1.6 internal server to a new ubuntu 20.04 / apache 2.4.41 / php 7.4.3 server.

I'd like (in developing) have error displayed in browser, and not the HTTP ERROR 500!! Just like the old server do!
Take this little script:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "ciao"
echo "ciao"
echo "ciao"
echo "ciao"
?>
```

Running in the old server i have this response:

> Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';' in D:\www\progettoru_php\ciao.php on line 7

While in the new server i have the HTTP ERROR 500, of course in the server log i can see

> [Fri Jun 17 13:10:16.485612 2022] [php7:error] [pid 1718] [client 172.16.0.222:14657] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ';' or ',' in /dati/intranet/helpdesk/ciao.php on line 7

But it's annoying to switch between the client and the server...
any **TRUE** solution?
Thankyou
Marco

Comment: The file cannot be executed due to the parse errors, so the ini_set lines never actually affect anything. If you changed the settings in the php.ini, it would show the way you want.

Comment: _"Running in the old server i have this response:"_ - but _not_ because of those `ini_set` lines ...

Comment: YES! the solution is putting in php.ini all this settings! Thankyou CBroe